# Adding user input to JSON array in PHP using $_POST returns "null" array

Tags: php, arrays, json, input, associative

I am trying to add user input into a JSON file of multidimensional array using $_POST and ive finally got it to write into the JSON file, however it just displays: {"name":null,"date":null,"time":null,"organiser":null,"location":null}
I think the issue is somewhere in the $inputobj. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="events.json"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Event Submission Form</h1>
    <form action="events.json" method='POST' id='eventform'>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name of Event ">
        <input type="text" name="uiorganiser" placeholder="Organiser ">
        <input type="text" name="uilocation" placeholder="Location">
        <input type="date" name="uidate" placeholder="Date ">
        <input type="time" name="uitime" placeholder="Time ">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="getForm()" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="location.href='logout.php';">

<script>
        <?php
      

        $inputobj = array(          //creates array of key value pairs for user input
            'name' => $_POST['uiname'], 'date' => $_POST['uidate'],
            'time' => $_POST['uitime'], 'organiser' => $_POST['uiorganiser'], 'location' => $_POST['uilocation']
        );
        
        $jsonText = json_encode($inputobj);       //encodes new array into $jsonText variable
        $file = 'events.json';                    //gets og json file (og=original)
        $content = file_get_contents($file);      //stores og json file data as a string in $content variable
        $obj = json_decode($content, true);       //decodes original json data and stores it as associative array 
        array_push($obj, $inputobj);                
        $data = json_encode($obj);
        var_dump($data);
        file_put_contents('events.json',$data);
        ?>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$_POST['uiname']` is wrong, should be `$_POST['name']` instead of: `$inputobj = array(....);` try: `$inputobj = [....];`

Comment: Most welcome :)